# firefox selenium webdriver asking "FirefoxDriverServer.cs"

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, reference, webdriver

I have added correctly the selenium webdriver and the references into visual studio project, but still ask me to find "FirefoxDriverServer.cs"
See the capture:

[image]

What I must do? i'm trying to run webdriver using Mozilla Firefox

NOTE: I'm using C#, not java

---

With Nuget I only add the webdriver, and then I add the references with right click into "references" and the "add reference"
like this

[image]

then i press "accepted" and appears a message saying that I can be adde reference because it already exist in the proyect.  I press "accept"

![enter image description here][3]

And this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you added all the references? though NuGet?

Comment: look my update post please to see more infor about your questions please, With Nuget I only add the webdriver, and then I add the references with right click into "references" and the "add reference"
like this
http://i.imgur.com/Af0l4h1.jpg
then i press "accepted" and appears a message saying that I can be adde reference because it already exist in the proyect.  I press "accept"
http://i.imgur.com/SPjGBNw.jpg
And this is what I get:
http://i.imgur.com/WTuDjsY.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me. But, could be a simple missing step as well. See my recording [here](http://screencast.com/t/9HvygCw6t) to know how I do it from the scratch.

Comment: Thanks, but can you show me how to do it with Mozilla Firefox (i don't use chrome)